# LISP better understanding of multilevel lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to gain a better understanding of multilevel lists in lisp by making a function in which I delete all the elements that are not numbers from a multilevel list. I first try to flatten it  with striv0 function and then check if the first argument of the list is numerical or not. However I have a problem when trying the function
(func '(5 (5 2 (8)(7 (9)5))))
. I get :COND :variable IF HAS NO VALUE

The code :

```
    (DEFUN striv0 (lis)
(COND        ((NULL lis) NIL)
    ((ATOM lis) (LIST lis))
    (T (APPEND (striv0 (FIRST lis))
            (striv0 (REST lis))))
))

(DEFUN func (lis) 
(LET( (newList (striv0 lis))  ))
(COND ((NULL newList) NIL)
    ( T(IF (NUMBERP (FIRST newList))   
             ((func(REST newList)))))))
```

I believe I have managed to solve the problem by molding the second function into the first by checking for numerical arguments or inner lists if it's neither one it moves further along the list.:

```
    (DEFUN  checkNumber (lis)
(COND    ((NULL lis) NIL)
    ((ATOM lis) (LIST lis))
    (T (if ( or(NUMBERP ( FIRST lis))(LISTP (FIRST lis)))
         (APPEND ( checkNumber (FIRST lis))
            ( checkNumber (REST lis)))
       ( checkNumber (REST lis))  )
     )   
)
)
```

Comment: The `COND` syntax is wrong in the second function. `(cond ... (if ...))` should be `(cond ... (t (if ...)))` like in the other function above. Also, you're calling `STRIV0`, but you're not doing anything with the return value, so it doesn't actually accomplish anything (`STRIV0` doesn't modify the argument, it returns a new list).

Comment: I have modified the code. However now I get "program stack overflow.RESET" . I traced the function and I can see that after flattening the list it doesn't do anything (except it writes func'(5 5 2 8 7 9 5) up to thounsands before crashing.

Comment: There are a few problems still. First, you should use `LET` to define the local variable instead of just `SETF`ing a non-existing variable. The stack overflow is caused by calling `FUNC` with the whole list again and again. You should call it on the `REST` of the list instead. Also, the `(append (first newList) ...)`, won't work, because the `FIRST` of `NEWLIST` is a number, but `APPEND` expects lists. You should be using `CONS` instead. The call to `(append nil ...)` is also unnecessary, because appending a list to a `NIL` (an empty list) always results in the same list.

Comment: I have modified, however is it accepted in lisp to leave an IF statement without an else clause? Also, when I apply func on REST  newList it should redo all the steps, does that mean that when doing the flattening it overflows because there is no nested lists?

Comment: It's important that you format program code in a readable way. What you have posted is unfortunately unreadable. Try do improve indentation and formatting. This is no different from any other programming language - since Lisp is written as nested lists, it is relatively easy to indent and format programs. You need see where lists in the code start and where they end.

Comment: @Maria You can have `IF` without an else-clause, but in this case you do need to call `FUNC` there (just no need to append to an empty list). The `LET` is currently missing a pair of parentheses: `(let ((variable value) ...) body)` rather than just `(let (variable value) body)` and the body should be inside the `LET` form. When you're calling `FUNC` recursively, the way it's written now means that it will try to flatten the list again on every call, but that won't cause errors (just extra work. It would be better to flatten the list before calling `FUNC`).

Answer (score 5):

Here some line-by-line feedback and some hints:

```
(DEFUN func (lis)                    ; why is this called FUNC
                                     ;   and not something useful?
                                     ; why is the variable called
                                     ;  LIS and not LIST?

(LET( (newList (striv0 lis))  ))     ; why is this not indented?
                                     ; why does LET not have
                                     ;   body forms?
                                     ; why is the LET ending here?


(COND ((NULL newList) NIL)           ; why is this not indented?
    ( T(IF (NUMBERP (FIRST newList)) ; why is this not indented?
             ((func(REST newList)))))))  ; why are there so
                                         ;   many parentheses?
                                         ; why is it starting
                                         ;   with two parentheses?
```

Answer (score 4):

First, format your code.  The accepted convention is to use lower-case symbols and separate word parts within the symbol names with dashes, e. g. `new-list`.  Indentation is used to align forms of the same level at the same text column.  There are various write-ups of Lisp style, [here](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html#formatting-lisp-code) is one.  Here is how your code would look then:

```
(defun striv0 (lis)
  (cond ((null lis) nil)
        ((atom lis) (list lis))
        (t (append (striv0 (first lis))
                   (striv0 (rest lis))))))

(defun func (lis) 
  (let ((new-list (striv0 lis))))
  (cond ((null new-list) nil)
        (t (if (numberp (first new-list))
               (cons (first new-list) (func (rest new-list)))))))
```

A good editor will do the indentation for you.  If the indentation then does not match your expectation, you know that you made a syntax mistake.  The editor will also show matching parenthesis pairs.

`Let` takes as first argument a list of bindings and then any number of forms in its *body*.  Only within that body are the bindings in effect.  You want to put your `cond` form into that body:

```
(defun func (lis) 
  (let ((new-list (striv0 lis)))
    (cond ((null new-list) nil)
          (t (if (numberp (first new-list))
                 ((func (rest new-list))))))))
```

Note how the indentation automatically reflects the code structure: the `cond` form is now indented two spaces to show that it is inside the `let` body.  What I actually edited is to move the closing parenthesis of the `let` form to the end.

That last form `((func (rest new-list)))` is not a valid Lisp form there.  A form must always start with an operator (which can either be a symbol or a lambda form).  I think that you had something that looked right in an earlier version of your question: `(cons (first new-list) (func (rest new-list)))`.

I'd now try to find better names for those functions.  Your `striv0` might conventionally be named `flatten`.  “Multilevel lists” are usually called “trees” in Lisp.  Your `func` might thus be called `keep-numbers-from-tree`.

I'm not sure whether the flattening is part of your requirements.  In any case, I'd keep this separate, since it seem superfluous to do this again each time through the recursion.  First flatten, then filter numbers.

If flattening is not part of your requirements, don't do it.  When going through the tree, there are only three possibilities at each point: it is a list (then recurse), it is a number (keep), or it is a non-numeric atom (skip).

Comment: What editor do you recommend to use for lisp? Usually I use notepad for writing in lisp or other languages (or visual studio but only for  C++)

Comment: I usually use Emacs, or Vim in a pinch, but learning that often is an additional task that may distract from the goal of learning Lisp (even though Emacs is mostly built, extended, and configured in its own Lisp dialect).  I think that Atom or Sublime might provide more familiar environments for Windows users, though I'm not sure about the plugin situation for Lisp there.  If you want to go the Emacs route, take a look at Portacle, which bundles everything you need in a portable way.